# Creating a button to hide Woocommerce out of stock products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

so I have some code to show an 'out of stock' box under a product, if a product is out of stock.

I would like to have this so I tick a box and the out of stock products 'hide'. Then I untick this box, and they unhide.

```
// display an 'Out of Stock' label on archive pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_stock', 10 );
function woocommerce_template_loop_stock() {
global $product;
if ( ! $product->managing_stock() && ! $product->is_in_stock() )
    echo '<p class="stock out-of-stock">Out of Stock</p>';
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_availability_text', 'custom_backorders_stock_availability_text', 10, 2 );
function custom_backorders_stock_availability_text( $availability, $product ) {
if ( $product->managing_stock() && $product->is_on_backorder( 1 ) ) {
    if ( ! $product->backorders_require_notification() ) {
        $availability = __( 'Out of stock', 'woocommerce' );
    }
}
return $availability;
}
```

Tick box code (below) to hide prices on tick/untick. Can I do this with out of stock css?

```
<script>
$(function() {
var status = localStorage.getItem('chkStatus');
if(status == 'true'){
$("span.price").css("display", "none");
$("p.price").css("display", "none");
$(".tradePriceToggle").attr('checked', true)
}
else{
$("span.price").css("display", "block");
$("p.price").css("display", "block");
$(".tradePriceToggle").attr('checked', false)
}
$(".tradePriceToggle").click(function() {
if (this.checked) {
  $("span.price").hide();
  $("p.price").hide();
}
else {
  $("span.price").show();
  $("p.price").show();
}
localStorage.setItem("chkStatus", this.checked);
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://quadlayers.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/hide-out-of-stock-products-woocommerce-settings.gif

Comment: hey, yes thankyou for this. however i want this to be enabled by ticking a box rather than the woocommerce backend.

is there a way of referencing out of stock products with css?

Comment: and where would that box will be ?

Comment: anywhere, it's a tickbox. i'll update the code to show how the tickbox works.
if i can apply this same method to out of stock products, the problem is solved.

Comment: The jquery that you posted just hides it as html. You want product itself to be hidden or the message out of stock ? Its unclear what u want to hide.

Comment: Understood - I want the product/html itself to be hidden, so in this case, the product is wrapped ina  'product_card' div, so if there were an .outofstock .product_card property which targets out of stock specifically, we're done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247361/discussion-between-martin-mirchev-and-paul-m).